# Open LDAP Server migration

Tags: ubuntu, openldap, arch-linux

Im trying to migrate an Open LDAP Server from Ubuntu LTS 
to Arch Linux. So I followed the Guid by [Alex Pánek](http://blog.panek.work/2015/08/29/openldap_backup_restore.html).

So first I backuped the Databases from the Ubuntu Maschine:

```
ubuntu$ sudo slapcat -b cn=config -l cn=config.master.ldif
ubuntu$ sudo slapcat -l dc=example-dc=com.ldif
```

After that I copied this Files an the SSL Certificates to 
the *clean* Open LDAP Server on Arch Linux. Regarding that 
Arch uses not the same Directory Structure as Ubuntu. I've 
edited all Directory Entries in the Configuration Export 
from `/etc/ldap` to `/etc/openldap/` and 
`/var/lib/ldap/` to `/var/lib/openldap/`.

Then I startet the Import this works fine:

```
arch$ sudo slapadd -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d -b cn=config -l cn=config.master.ldif
_#################### 100.00% eta   none elapsed            none fast!
Closing DB...
```

After the Import I can start the LDAP Server normally. 
I've stopped the Server again and tried to Import the 
Domain Database with:

```
arch$ sudo slapadd -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d -b dc=example,dc=com -l ~/dc=example-dc=com.ldif
571e4715 hdb_monitor_db_open: monitoring disabled; configure monitor database to enable
slapadd: line 1: database #1 (dc=example,dc=com) not configured to hold "dc=com"; no database configured for that naming context
_                       2.36% eta   none elapsed            none spd   3.9 M/s
Closing DB...
```

I've no Idea where this Error is coming from and how to solve it.

Comment: I've testet it also with an new Ubuntu installation and I get the same Results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I did it by copying the library from the old server to the new one. I started ldapd and it's just worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

In my desperation I removed the first few Lines wich referenced only `dc=com`. Turns out, that this Lines not really necessary and the Import is now working fine. I've no Idea where this Lines coming from.

Comment: If this resolved your issue please accept your answer by clicking the checkmark.